# Is there a condition in terraform same as CloudFormation?

Tags: terraform

I see people using count to block resource creation in terraform. I want to create some resources if a condition is set to true. Is there such a thing same as in [CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html)?

Comment: There are conditions but you have to show what you want to use them for.

Answer (score 1):

You answered yourself, the most similar thing is the `count`

You can use it combined with a **conditional expression**, like

```
resource "x" "y"{
  count = var.tag == "to_deploy" ? 1 : 0
}
```

But this is just a stupid example, you can put everything, also use functions

```
count = max(var.array) >= 3 ? 1 : 0
```

And if you need to put a condition on something more complex, you can evaluate to use a `locals` block where do all elaboration you need, and just use some bool, or what you want, resultant from that in conditional expression.

I would like to help you more, but I should know your specific case, what are the conditions you would have.

Answer (score 1):

In CloudFormation a "condition" is a top-level object type alongside resources, outputs, mappings, etc.

The Terraform language takes a slightly more general approach of just having values of various data types, combining and transforming them using expressions. Therefore there isn't a concept exactly equivalent to CloudFormation's "conditions", but you can achieve a similar effect in other ways using Terraform.

For example, if you want to encode the decision rule in only a single place and then refer to it many times then you can define a [Local Value](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals) of boolean type and then refer to that from multiple `resource` blocks. A local value of boolean type is essentially equivalent to a condition object in CloudFormation. The CloudFormation documentation page you linked to has, at the time of writing, an example titled "Simple condition" and the following is a roughly-equivalent version of that example in the Terraform language:

```
variable "environment_type" {
  type = string

  validation {
    condition     = contains(["prod", "test"], var.environment_type)
    error_message = "Must be either 'prod' or 'test'."
  }
}

locals {
  create_prod_resources = (var.environment_type == "prod")
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-0ff8a91507f77f867"
  instance_type = "..."
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "example" {
  count = local.create_prod_resources ? 1 : 0

  availability_zone = aws_instance.example.availability_zone
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "example" {
  count = local.create_prod_resources ? 1 : 0

  volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.example[count.index].id
  instance_id = aws_instance.example.id
  device      = "/dev/sdh"
}
```

Two different `resource` blocks can both refer to `local.create_prod_resources`, in the same way that the two resources `MountPoint` and `NewVolume` can refer to the shared condition `CreateProdResources` in the CloudFormation example.